# VS2017 C++ Standard Library Modules

Tags: c++, module, visual-studio-2017

VS2017 comes with the possibility to install Standard Library Modules.

In fact in `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\ifc\` there are ifc module definition files and `std.lib` for x86/x64 and Debug/Release. How do we use them? How do you link against them? And what exactly is available in these standard modules?

Comment: At least for what's available. They should contain everything that's part of the standard library. Just using the module system proposed for standardization

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-modules-in-vs-2015-update-1/

Comment: I already read that, even used it in VS Preview. What I want to know is how do we use them on a day to day basis, with the VS RTM, how do you configure a project to work with module (and not the CLI).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the following code sample working:

```
import std.core;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

by passing these extra parameters to the compiler:

```
/experimental:module /module:search "path-to-standard-library-ifc-modules"
```

and providing the full path to std.lib in the ifc folder to the linker

```
properties->linker->additional dependencies
```

EDIT:

Adding some additional info since this was the only Google result i found regarding this question:

On my computer these files are located in:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\ifc
```

They are installed when the "standard library modules" component is selected during installation of visual studio 2017.